# Restrict which HTTP methods on a loopback model relationship

Tags: models, loopbackjs, has-many, http-method

So I have a venue model with the following rellationship:

```
relations": {
  "events": {
    "type": "hasMany",
    "model": "event"
  },
},
```

In the events I have the relationship as:

```
"relations": {
    "venue": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "venue",
      "foreignKey": "venueId",
      "options": {
        "validate": true,
        "forceId": false
      }
    }
  },
```

In the explorer it shows me that I can get, put, post, patch, update and delete to `venue/:id/events`

Where and how do I say: **no matter who you are, this specific relationship can ONLY have GET access and nothing else?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `hasMany` Loopback adds the following methods:

```
__findById__events
__destroyById__events
__updateById__events
__get__events
__create__events
__delete__events
__count__events
```

Since you only want get access we keep `findById`, `get` and `count`, and disable the rest.

Assuming you are using Loopback 3, you can do this in your model:

```
Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('prototype.__destroyById__events');
Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('prototype.__updateById__events');
Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('prototype.__create__events');
Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('prototype.__delete__events');
```

Have a look at [the documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Exposing-models-over-REST.html#hiding-endpoints-for-related-models) for the more info.

If you are using Loopback 2 you should do this instead(initally written by [Kiley Hykawy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22727/kiley-hykawy)):

```
Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('__destroyById__events', false);
Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('__updateById__events', false);
Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('__create__events', false);
Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('__delete__events', false);
```

`false` is needed to indicate that it is a non-static method, like prototype for LoopBack 3.

Comment: For LoopBack 2, you can do this in your model:
    Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('__destroyById__events', false);
    Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('__updateById__events', false);
    Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('__create__events', false);
    Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('__delete__events', false);
    Message.disableRemoteMethodByName('__count__events', false);

false is needed to indicate that it is a non-static method, like prototype for LoopBack 3.

Comment: @KileyHykawy I added that to the answer with your permission.